# Wordpress - wp-admin can't be found

Tags: php, wordpress

I maintain a non-profit wordpress site for a relative.  Recently, they have not been able to login to post.  I tried logging on as admin and get a 404 for wp-admin.php.  I searched and tried a number of "solutions", such as disabling the theme, deleting .htaccess, modiying .htaccess, adding the site url to wp-config.php, and so on.  Absolutely nothing is working.  I also cannot access phpmyadmin - I get the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in \phpMyAdmin\index.php on line 60`

Line 60 is as follows: `&& Core::checkPageValidity($_REQUEST['target'], [], true)`

I have no idea how to fix this as I'm a vb.net dev with no php experience.  Please help. Thanks!

[EDIT] I just found an email from last week about my host upgrading MySQL 5.7.17 to 5.7.29.  Based on what my relative said about not being able to log in since last week, this could be the issue.  I have contacted my hosting provider.

Comment: Hey, the message is about a Parse error on phpMyAdmin, nothing related to the Wordpress installation/configuration. Would you care to share a little bit about how's this Wordpress hosted? In any case, I think reinstalling phpMyAdmin would fix the problem...

Comment: Daniel Faria Sampaio, I use https://www.winhost.com/ and installed Wordpress via the site manager accessible at cp.winhost.com.  I've had this running for 4 years now and occasionally log in to update everything.  I haven't touched it in a few months so I'm not sure why this would happen. As for phpmyadmin, I think I manually installed it a year ago.

Comment: Hmm this is very odd. As your EDIT message states, it might be related to the MySQL upgrade process, but I imagine that such thing would not take that much time. Contact your host provider either way

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the MySQL update messed with the wordpress database. If you have SSH access to the machine I would recommend trying to connect to mysql through terminal to make sure it's still running.

```
sudo service mysqld status
```

should show you if mysql is running. if it is then just connect to it:

```
mysql - u root -p
```

If your provider only provided you with only user access you can still use the username instead of root example:

```
mysql - u username -p PASSWORDHERE
```

Once you are in check the list of databases and find the one for phpmyadmin and wordpress and run a check command to see if there are any issues in the databases.

That would be my take at it.
Share more information if what I am saying doesn't make sense.